# Removing JavaFX ListView borders

Tags: listview, javafx, javafx-2

I'm trying to completly remove ListView borders from my app (in css) but nothing works.

There is structure in FXML like:
HBox > AnchorPane > ListView

I tried to apply:

```
-fx-border-width: 0px;
```

to .hbox, .anchorpane (classes applied to nodes), .list-view and .list-cell but it looks like there is something more inside listview that still has border. How to remove it completely?

edit: problem solved. It was caused by default -fx-padding: 1px;

[image: listview borders]

Comment: can you please post it as an answer so it comes out answered?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is to use:

```
-fx-padding: 1px;
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, but `-fx-padding: 0px;` did.

Answer (score 12):

Remove JavaFX default control border (e.g., for ListView and SplitPane):

```
.list-view, .split-pane { -fx-background-insets: 0; -fx-padding: 0; }
```